# Concatenar duas variáveis em uma utilizando LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Por meio do LINQ eu faço uma consulta no banco de dados nos campos **CPF** e **CNPJ** da tabela **Pessoas** e preciso atribuir esses dois campos da tabela a uma única variável **Documento** para apresentar em tela. De acordo com o código abaixo que tenho, como posso concatenar esses dois campos, atribuindo os valores uma única variável?

```cs
var mapeamento = new DataColumnMappingCollection
{
    {nameof (Pessoa.Id), "Código"},
    {nameof (Pessoa.Nome), "Nome"},
    {nameof (Pessoa.CPF), "CPF"},
    {nameof (Pessoa.CNPJ), "CNPJ"},
    {nameof (Pessoa.Apelido), "Apelido"},
};

OrigemDados = new OrigemDados(
    pessoaService
        .RecuperarTodos(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User)
        .Select(pessoa => new { pessoa.Id, pessoa.Nome, pessoa.CPF, pessoa.CNPJ, pessoa.Apelido})
        .AsQueryable(),
    usuario => usuario
        .GetType()
        .GetProperty("Nome")
        .GetValue(usuario)
        .ToString(),
    mapeamento);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resposta ao problema apresentado:

Na linha onde é aplicado o `Select`, concatenar `pessoa.CPF` com `pessoa.CNPJ` utilizando o operador de soma **+**, atribuindo a concatenação a uma variável criada ali mesmo, no caso do exemplo, a variável **Documento**.

O resultado é **Documento = pessoa.CPF + pessoa.CNPJ**

Isto retornará uma única variável **Documento** que poderá conter o dado de CPF ou de CNPJ.

```cs
var mapeamento = new DataColumnMappingCollection
{
    {nameof (Pessoa.Id), "Código"},
    {nameof (Pessoa.Nome), "Nome"},
    {nameof (Pessoa.CPF), "CPF"},
    {nameof (Pessoa.CNPJ), "CNPJ"},
    {nameof (Pessoa.Apelido), "Apelido"},
};

OrigemDados = new OrigemDados(
    pessoaService
        .RecuperarTodos(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User)
        .Select(pessoa => new { pessoa.Id, pessoa.Nome, Documento = pessoa.CPF + pessoa.CNPJ, pessoa.Apelido})
        .AsQueryable(),
    usuario => usuario
        .GetType()
        .GetProperty("Nome")
        .GetValue(usuario)
        .ToString(),
    mapeamento);
```